# resolver código no matlab?

Tags: matlab

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse problema?

Preciso multiplicar uma expressão por 'x' e obter o resultado.

A expressão é: A1 - A1*x + 2*A2*x - A2 x^2 + 3*A3*x^2 - A3*x^3 + 4*A4*x^3 - A4*x^4  + 5*A5*x^4 - A5*x^5 - 1

Preciso multiplica-la por 'x'. Como fazer?

Comment: Qual é o código que tem até agora? Deu algum erro? Qual?

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente você tem um erro na sua expressão `A2 x^2`, considerando isso como `A2*x^2`, vamos ao problema.

Matlab tem uma sintaxe bem simples: 
Caso tenha-se `a` e se queira multiplicar `a` vezes `x`, basta usar

```
a*x
```

Caso `a` seja algo mais complexo do que apenas uma simples variável ou número, convém usar parenteses para fazer a multiplicacão da maneira correta ficando assim:

```
(a)*x
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema. Obrigada